# .htaccess URL rewrite works, but address bar then shows 'dirty' URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

- User clicks link (from their email): `http://www.site.com/edit/wih293f73y`
- Browser window opens and gets them to the correct page.
- But now the browser's address bar shows: `http://www.site.com/editor.php?editCode=wih293f73y`

**Extra info:**

- My rewrite rule is:`RewriteRule    ^edit/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    editor.php?editCode=$1    [NC,L]`
- This problem ONLY occurs when the user has clicked a link. It works perfectly when you just type the pretty url into the address bar.
- This problem **ONLY occurs for links that include the `www.`** - the link `http://site.com/edit/wih293f73y` works like a charm.
- My .htaccess file includes the following code (from HTML5 boilerplate, which I wasn't aware of previously):

> ```
> # Rewrite www.example.com → example.com
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
>     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
>     RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

If it's important, this occurs after my other rewrite rules.

Comment: You are certain there is no `[R]` flag in there to perform a redirection?

Comment: Yeah, that's the whole line. I'm using the HTML5 boilerplate .htaccess file though, so would it have set any defaults? the string "[R]" doesn't occur in it though (it's a pretty long file). [also, I added some extra info in the question]

Comment: problem is for htaccess code that check referrer search for `HTTP_REFERER` in htaccess code

Comment: I tried googling this `HTTP_REFERER` but am still not sure what you mean? I searched my .htaccess file for "HTTP_REFERER" and it doesn't occur in there.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think you were on to something! Please take a look at the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a look and it is apparent that your `www` rules is causing this. Question is do you want it be fixed? If you do then move this rule on top of all other rules and your problem should be fixed.

**Move this to top of all other rules**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use the redirect directive

> redirect 301 ^edit/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ editor.php?editCode=$1

There are some pros and cons to this strategy. The pros being;

- It's super fast. You don't even need to load up your application for this to work.
- It's minimal code.
- Redirects are an intrinsic part of Apache (or any http server) and aren't going anywhere soon.

The cons being;

- It's not part of your application proper. Should you decide to change logic or URLs, you'll have to change this, too.
- It's slower, as you need to invoke php, as opposed to just having Apache issue the redirect.

Comment: Hi Chris, is this a good strategy? I'm pretty new to .htaccess so I just want to be sure I'm not taking any shortcuts that will bite me later. Isn't this just a simple task - there shouldn't be anything difficult about a simple rewrite should there? Or is the problem that you need more info to know why it's not working?

Comment: Behaviour between clicking a link and entering the URL should be identical. If you think there's a difference, you may want to look into what else the email is doing.

Comment: Yeah, it's strange - but it occurs with any links, not just from emails. I tested it with links from websites as well. If you've got a moment, I've put a few edits in the question which are probably pretty big clues